# .js show hide hidden div within hidden div

Tags: javascript, html

Thank you in advance for your help!  It's my first post, wasn't sure about the formatting so I hope I've done it correctly.

I'd like to know if I can show/hide hidden Nested divs using the following script taken from http://www.huntingground.freeserve.co.uk/main/mainfram.htm?../style/lyr_swap.htm:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function swapLyr(num) {
idCount=0

while(document.getElementById("mydiv"+idCount)){
el=document.getElementById("mydiv"+idCount)

if(idCount != num){
el.style.display="none"
}
else{
el.style.display="block"
}

idCount++

}

}

</script>

<ul>
<li onclick="swapLyr(0)">Show Green</li>
<li onclick="swapLyr(1)">Show Yellow</li> 
<li onclick="swapLyr(2)">Show Red</li>
<li onclick="swapLyr(3)">Show Blue</li>
</ul>

<div id="mydiv0" style="display:none;background-color:#00AA00;width:350px; height:260px">Green</div>
<div id="mydiv1" style="display:none;background-color:#AAAA00;width:350px; height:260px">Yellow</div>
<div id="mydiv2" style="display:none;background-color:#AA0000;width:350px; height:260px">Red</div>
<div id="mydiv3" style="display:none;background-color:#0000AA;width:350px; height:260px">Blue</div>
```

I would like to use something like:

```
<div id="mydiv3" style="display:none;background-color:#0000AA;width:350px; height:260px">Blue<br /><br />
    <a href="#null" onclick="swapLyr(5)">Show Hidden Div within this Div</li>
    <div id="mydiv5" style="display:none;background-color:#FFF;width:300px; height:210px">Hidden Div Within "Blue" div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried using your code? does it work?

Comment: @Ibu - Yes, I've tried and nothing happens.  I've also tried using several of the show/hide solutions here on SO but no joy so far.

Comment: the div with id mydiv3 is hidden. so... you better explain it better. the first code is the part taken and the second part is your code???

Comment: @machineaddict - "mydiv3" is already hidden by default, yes (until it is clicked on).

I would like to click the link to display "mydiv3" content, which will include a link to display a further hidden <div> within "mydiv3". Thanks for the ask.

Comment: Do you understand what this code is doing? If not, I would start with learning the basics of JavaScript, here is a great FREE resource http://learn.appendto.com/ best of luck!

Comment: if it is hidden, you cannot click it... And please answer my first question.

Comment: @Paul - Yes, I do and I have used this code many times in the past.  I've even tried using a second .js function to show/hide additional content within a <div> that has been changed from display:none to display:block but no go.

Comment: @machineaddict - My apologies... the first part is original code, second part is my example code.  I don't expect to be able to show a hidden child <div> unless the parent <div> is visible, so of course the parent <div> will be visible before I can have the user click the link to display the hidden child <div> within the now visible parent <div>.

Answer (score -1):

i see it know. use this:

```
<div id="mydiv3" style="background-color:#0000AA;width:350px; height:260px">Blue<br /><br />
    <a href="#" onclick="swapLyr(5);">Show Hidden Div within this Div</a>
    <div id="mydiv5" style="display:none;background-color:#FFF;width:300px; height:210px">Hidden Div Within "Blue" div</div>
</div>
<script>
function swapLyr(num) {
    el=document.getElementById("mydiv"+num);
    if(el.style.display=="none"){
        el.style.display="block";
    }else{
        el.style.display="none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for the code example, I ran it in jsfiddle.net but that didn't work for me.  I've now recoded my page with an alternative solution for this issue, would like to thank everyone for their help.